# SQLite all columns specified with DEFAULT in DDL cause error. Can't insert any data now

Tags: sqlite, binary, default, create-table

It's been a while since I used SQL, and I am relearning a lot. However, I cannot figure out why my `DEFAULT` values are causing errors in my SQL with SQLite. I have created 4 tables, and most of them use `DEFAULT` values of some sort.

Before, I was able to create test data in my database (with these default values). Now, for some reason, these cause errors, and I cannot figure out why.

## DDL

Here is one of my tables. Look at the last 4 columns in the SQL (i.e. `is_usdr_created`, `is_continuous_play`, `is_random_play`, `repeat_all_play`)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (
  playlist_id        INT  NOT NULL,
  category_id        INT  NOT NULL,
  name               TEXT NOT NULL CHECK (trim(name) != ''),
  video_count        INT CHECK (video_count > 0),
  is_user_created    BOOLEAN DEFAULT (0),
  is_continuous_play BOOLEAN DEFAULT (1),
  is_random_play     BOOLEAN DEFAULT (0),
  repeat_all_play    BOOLEAN DEFAULT (0),

  PRIMARY KEY (playlist_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (category_id)
);
```

## Error

```
[1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "DEFAULT": syntax error)
```

If I remove all the `DEFAULT` keywords and values, then everything works fine. Why is that?

---

NOTE: I just edited this once I realized this problem is now more widespread to all my tables with default values.

I also decided to create a new project, just in case this was an issue with the previous project; however, this issue is still occuring with the new project.

Comment: Actually, I just retested my other tables, and they are not working either. I had an issue with JetBrain's DataGrip IDE and lost all my DDL's ... except what I had saved in a log by chance. I just copy-pasted that DDL in and recreated my tables with that

Comment: Which version do you use? It looks correct **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b0af2/1/0)** Show your entire script

Comment: `SQLite 3.8.9`  I am using JetBrain DataGrip 1.0.1 and using the default drivers provided by the IDE

Comment: @lad2025 I updated the question

Comment: It is weird. Now it works fine. I played around with sqlfiddle.com for a while and got a working script that I like. Tested it in DataGrip, and things just work.